# Why does textInst not exist in the current context if i declared it above? I can't make it public

Tags: c#, variables

I am attempting to insert data from a text box into a database. In my SQL command statement, I use a variable substitution and reference it to the value of the text box. For some reason, it says that it doesn't, even though I just referenced it above. Is it because the string isn't public, because when I make it public, I get a whole load of errors such as saying all of my strings don't exist in the current context. How do I solve this?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace idk
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string connString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string textInst = textBox1.Text;
        }


    private void openDBBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
    }

    private void instBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS(Name) VALUES(@textInst)";
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn2))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textInst", textInst);
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeDBBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn3 = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn3.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You declared it within the scope of `textBox1_TextChanged`. That means it can only be seen within that event/method. You would need to define it within the scope of the class instead.

Comment: Besides, the closedb button just creates a connection only to close it! There is no reason for that button to even exists. And the open button just does the same, creates a connection and immediately closes it. The insert opens, uses and closes the connection already, in the proper way.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 Or not at all. It is superfluent. You can take it directly from the Component's Text property.

Comment: @Fildor haha indeed you can.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. I fixed the problem I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string connString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

    string textInst {get;set;}

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textInst = textBox1.Text;
    }


}
```